# Matching 10 or 12 digits with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to C# and coming from PHP background.

I wanted to validate only 10 and 12 digits only with following regex statment.
I got correct regex. But still I'm getting invalid number error if tested

Pleae point me out where I do the mistake here.
Code is compiled without any issues.

```
  // To validate 10 digits or 10 digits only

  string regxstr = "^(?=[0-9]*$)(?:.{10}|.{12})$";

  if (Regex.IsMatch(Data.number, regxstr))
  {
     return "Valid number";
  }
  else {
    return "Invalid number";
  }
```

Comment: What input did you use? I used `111111111111` and it prints "Valid number".

Comment: I tested with 10001001l203. I get invalid number error. I pass this through API in an XML node <pos:number>10001001l203</pos:number>

Comment: @D-Shih you are correct. I noticed only after you pointed it out. Regex is valid. Thank you both Sweeper for taking time to reply. :)

Comment: @RoshanRuzaik "C# Regex help needed" is a poor title for a question. I will fix that for you; but please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand the importance of the title, and see how similar this title is to the bad example titles.

Comment: @Richardissimo , thank you for editing. Sure will follow the guidelines in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your testing data does not consists of only digits.

You could simplify your regex to match 10 digits `\d{10}` with and optional group that matches 2 digits `(?:\d{2})?`.

[`^\d{10}(?:\d{2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/N2DJYx/1/)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NCN56256)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why don't you use simple regular expression for this like:

```
^(\d{10}|\d{12})$
```